# How can I bypass React's useEffect() "missing dependency" warning?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io, use-effect

I am creating a chat app in React using socket.io. I don't need the following useEffect() to run more than once, and what this warning message is asking me to resolve would conflict with my intention of setting the socket message handler only once:

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'messages'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. You can also do a functional update 'handleMessages(m => ...)' if you only need 'messages' in the 'handleMessages' call.eslintreact-hooks/exhaustive-deps

```
export default function Group(props) {

    const [_broadcastOptions, handleBroadcastOptions] = useState(false);
    const [messages, handleMessages] = useState([]);
    const textValue = useRef('');
    const bottomScrollRef = useRef();
    const socket = useRef();
   
    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log('bruh');

        socket.current = io('http://0.0.0.0:3001');
        
        socket.current.on('connect', ()=> {
            console.log('socket connection status: ' + socket.current.connected);
            socket.current.emit('enter-room', getRoomId(window.location.pathname));
        });
        socket.current.on('message', m => {
            console.log('message received: ' + JSON.stringify(m));
            handleMessages([...messages, m]);
        });
    }, []);
return (...);
}
```

Edit: I've tried passing in a callback in my handleMessages function (functional updates as react calls them) but I still get the warning.

[image: Warning persists even with functional updating]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the callback for `handleMessages` instead, there's no need to use the outer `messages` identifier (which would be in an old closure anyway).

```
    socket.current.on('message', m => {
        console.log('message received: ' + JSON.stringify(m));
        handleMessages(messages => [...messages, m]);
    });
```

Comment: I still get the warning after doing this

Comment: Is the warning the exact same, warning about `messages`? That doesn't make any sense...

Comment: yes, it's the same. I edited my post with a screenshot of the warning

Comment: You forgot to use the argument in the callback - copy and paste the code from my answer exactly. `handleMessages(messages => [...messages, m]);`

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you should using a callback in the `handleMessages` to update state. You can read more in here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

```
handleMessages((preMessage) => [...preMessage, m]);
```

Comment: I've tried this. Oddly enough, I still get the warning

Comment: You don't have `preMessage`. Just copy paste

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure about this, add `// eslint-disable-next-line` before the line that shows the error.